# Xampp Install Complete BUT error msg

Tags: xampp

> Ports 80 or 443(SSL) already in use!

Yes I have read all the faqs on this, but I can not find what is running on port 80.  I am a newbie to programming and am very fustrated.  Any help would be appreciated.  So http://localhost ...does not work.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: If you have Skype, it will prevent you from using port 80.  Disable it from Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection

Comment: If you're on OSX, ensure that you don't have Web Sharing enabled. I had a friend who had the same problem. He was unaware OSX shipped with Apache and installed Xampp.

Comment: might want to check superuser.com or serverfault as well.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows

Run the following: `netstat -ano |find /i ":80"|find /i "LISTENING"` from the command line (Start -> Run -> type `cmd` enter).

You should take note of the last number in the data returned, this is the PID of whatever is currently running on port :80.

You can then open up your task manager, go to the Processes tab (ensure you are displaying PIDs by going to View -> Select Columns -> tick PID"). You should also ensure you're showing processes from all users - now you need to look for the PID that matches the one you got from the command above. This will tell you what is process is running on that port (and you can kill it).

### Linux/UNIX

Run the following command from the terminal: `netstat -npl|grep :80` this will give you something like:

```
tcp        0      0 :::80    :::*       LISTEN      1545/httpd
```

The PID is 1545, from there you can run `ps -p 1545 u` which will give you something like:

```
apache    1545  0.0  1.6  28952  8492 ?        S    Dec04   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
```

and magic, we know the binary is /usr/sbin/httpd.

Answer (score 0):

You're running Skype, aren't you?

I know because I'm watching you... **I'm standing right behind you**.

Just kidding! By default skype is set to take over port 80 and 443 for incoming connections. Go to skype and click Tools, Options, Advanced, Connections and untick the box that says "Use port 80 and 443 for incoming connections".